# Compiling a LibUSB 0.1 program fails with "undefined reference" errors

Tags: dependencies, compiling, gcc, c, shared-library

I have a small C program that uses `libusb 0.1`.

I've already installed `libusb-dev` (which basically means libusb 0.1: https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/libusb-dev) and included the header `<usb.h>`.

But compiling using `gcc -Wall -lusb -o te923con te923con.c te923usb.c te923com.c` is always failing. There are a lot of undefined references, including `usb_find_busses`, `usb_init`, and `usb_open`.

```
$ gcc -Wall -lusb -o te923con te923con.c te923usb.c te923com.c
/tmp/cc1TRIze.o: In function `find_te923':
te923usb.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `usb_find_busses'
te923usb.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `usb_find_devices'
te923usb.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `usb_get_busses'
/tmp/cc1TRIze.o: In function `te923_handle':
te923usb.c:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `usb_init'
te923usb.c:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `usb_open'
te923usb.c:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `usb_get_driver_np'
te923usb.c:(.text+0x1ab): undefined reference to `usb_detach_kernel_driver_np'
te923usb.c:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `usb_set_configuration'
te923usb.c:(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `usb_claim_interface'
te923usb.c:(.text+0x23d): undefined reference to `usb_set_altinterface'
/tmp/cc1TRIze.o: In function `te923_close':
te923usb.c:(.text+0x2b3): undefined reference to `usb_release_interface'
te923usb.c:(.text+0x2bf): undefined reference to `usb_close'
/tmp/ccxL1A67.o: In function `read_from_te923':
te923com.c:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `usb_control_msg'
te923com.c:(.text+0x28b): undefined reference to `usb_interrupt_read'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'te923con' failed
make: *** [te923con] Error 1
```

I don't understand the reason for these errors. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Most likely, link order. See for example [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: But the command "gcc -Wall -lusb -o te923con te923con.c te923usb.c te923com.c" is written by the program's author (http://te923.fukz.org/documentation.html). And I've already tested it on a virtual-box linux guest system using the same packages and the same ubuntu version like I'm using now on my real linux system. And there it worked.

Comment: Well it's simple enough to find out: `gcc -Wall -o te923con te923con.c te923usb.c te923com.c -lusb`

Comment: Jesus Christ! It's working! Thank you! But why?

Comment: Order of library is important now, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45218113/1212012

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I solved it

Instead of

```
  gcc -lusb -o outfile input.c
```

I used

```
  gcc -o outfile input.c -lusb
```

and that worked

Comment: It worked for me (Debian 11).